# how to Validate List columns in List-form in sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-form, validation

Am creating a custom list-forms using SP designer 2013 and trying to validate these fileds but whn am using the **reguler expresion validator** then am start getting error like

> Web Part Error: The type
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.RegularExpressionValidator, System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   could not be found or it is not registered as safe. Correlation ID:
>   c079b19d-b12c-80c8-20ae-ed7f8ba6c71a. Hide Error Details 
>   [UnsafeControlException: The type
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.RegularExpressionValidator, System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   could not be found or it is not registered as safe.]   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.EditingPageParser.VerifyControlOnSafeList(String
>   dscXml, RegisterDirectiveManager registerDirectiveManager, SPWeb web) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerWebApplication.Microsoft.Web.Design.Server.IServerWebApplication.CheckMarkupForSafeControls(String
>   controlMarkup, RegisterDirectiveManager registerDirectiveManager)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Design.Server.ServerDocument.CheckMarkupForSafeControls(String
>   outerHtml)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Design.Server.ServerDocument.Microsoft.Web.Design.Server.IServerDocumentDesigner.ParseControl(String
>   outerHtml)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CompressUsingMicrosoftWebDesigner(SourceContent
>   sourceContent, String allRegisterDirectives)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CompressInOrder(Deserializer
>   firstMethod, Deserializer secondMethod, SourceContent sourceContent,
>   String allRegisterDirectives, Boolean isClosed)

this error comes by simply adding validator to page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for validating list-forms fields we need to take either field id or value according to that we can validate any field.we can apply bellow code to achieve that

```
function PreSaveAction()
{
 var innerHtml="";
 var emailId = $("input[title='Email Id']")[0].value;
 var ContactNo=$("input[title='Contact No']")[0].value;
 var lngth=parseInt(ContactNo.length);
 var numExpression = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/; 
 var emailFilter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/; // /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

 if(emailId==="")
    {
        innerHtml+="Email Id can not be empty";
        $("#emailErrorMessage").html(innerHtml);   
        return false ;       
    }

    else if (emailFilter.test(emailId) === false) {
        innerHtml+="In-valid Email Id";
        $("#emailErrorMessage").html(innerHtml);   
        return false ;
     }
     else { 
         $("#emailErrorMessage").html(""); 
        return true ;
     }

 if(isNaN(parseInt(ContactNo))) {
         if(ContactNo==="")
         {
             innerHtml+="Contact No Can not be Empty";
             $("#contactNoErrorMessage").html(innerHtml);   
             return false ;
         }
         else
         {
             innerHtml+="you can enter only digits";
             $("#contactNoErrorMessage").html(innerHtml);   
             return false ;
         }
    }
    else if(!isNaN(parseInt(ContactNo)) && (lngth<10 ||lngth>10) )
    {
        innerHtml+="You can enter only 10 digits";
        $("#contactNoErrorMessage").html(innerHtml);   
        return false ;
    }

    else
    {  
        $("#contactNoErrorMessage").html("");   
        return true ;
    } 
}
```

but for this we have to add a script editor web part to that list form and in that script editor web part we have to put the validation code like above mensioned.